# EOS.IO utilization with Django?

Tags: javascript

Has anybody been able to utilize EosJs or any other type of implementation with django? I'd like to be able to build my dApp utilizing the testnet, but I'm not quite sure how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is: it all depends on your architecture.

My preferred architecture is to not have the user private key never. So I'm using eosjs in the UI with Scatter to sign transactions. And my application server receive requests and utilizes EOSRPC endpoints to sign transactions to my contracts with keys being handled by a `keosd` instance.

Now, you can generate and store the private keys on your application server and let the user utilizes the traditional authentication flow (email, password) to your server and you can sign everything for him. In this method you will only need to integrate with EOSRPC endpoints and that's it.

The EOSRPC is language agnostic since it's an HTTP JSON RPC, therefore you can use any language to send `POST` and `GET` requests. If you want an example of an EOSRPC wrapper you can check this elixir one that we developed: https://github.com/BeSpiral/eosrpc-elixir-wrapper

*EDIT: I was re-reading my answer and at the end I don't know if I answered your question correctly lol. I didn't brush Django/Python area, but I think if you want to stick to any of these architectures you would just add a js library in the frontend (eosjs + scatter) as you do with any other library when you work with django. And at the backend side, on python, you can always submit requests to EOSRPC.*

Answer (score 0):

It appears that @furion has started to build a python base library for EOS last year, but not much has been done on it in recent updates: https://github.com/Netherdrake/py-eos-base

That library looks similar to some other libs that @xeroc built, namely python-bitshares and python-steem.

If you want to call into EOS from a python-based web application, the first step would be probably be to fork and update the lib linked above, or create your own.